# FastClick Issue with webkit-overflow-scrolling

Tags: javascript, cordova, mobile-safari, fastclick.js, fastclick

I'm developing a cross-platform html5 app using cordova that is targeting android and iOS.
I'm having issues with [fastclick](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) on iOS devices. basically, in some cases when a click occurs during a scroll, it fires a click for the wrong element.
it seems like an old problem, that many have experienced, and is well described [here](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick/issues/319) and [here](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick/issues/227).
but I couldn't find any effective solution. those issues are more than a year old, and yet it seems that somehow everyone just lives with it.

My question is: Is there any solution that fixes this issue, so that I won't have to worry about scrolling in android or iOS ever again, and yet, keep the momentum scrolling feature in iOS devices.

Any solution preferably one that can be applied globally is welcome. if it's a different library, it should be easy to integrate with backbone.
I prefer not to add any more javascript or bind to scroll event unless it is really simple.

Comment: did you finally manage to solve this issue?

Comment: @stelioschar Sadly no :(